# Iterate through certain images in res/drawable-mdpi

Tags: android, android-resources, getresource

In the [res/drawable-mdpi](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/master/MyTiles/res/drawable-mdpi) folder I have 26 letter images, named **big_0.png** to **big_25.png**.

I would like to add them all (and ignore any other images in the folder) to a hash map:

```
private static HashMap<Character, Drawable> sHash = 
    new HashMap<Character, Drawable>();
```

Initially I was planning something like:

```
private static final CharacterIterator ABC = 
    new StringCharacterIterator("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");

int i = 0;
for (char c = ABC.first(); 
    c != CharacterIterator.DONE; 
    c = ABC.next(), i++) {

        String fileName = "R.drawable.big_" + i;
        Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(fileName);
        sHash.put(c, image);
}
```

But then I've realized that `R.drawable.big_0` to `R.drawable.big_25` are of type **int** and not **String**.

So please advise me, how to iterate through the 26 images correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `getResources().getIdentifier()` to convert `"R.drawable.big_" + i` into the resource ID value that you would use with `getDrawable()`.

Comment: `int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier("big_" + i,"drawable", context.getPackageName());` has worked for me, thanks. (And note to myself: when you forget to call `setBounds()` for the drawables - they are not visible).