# Iterating over drawables in Android

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

In Android, I have only found answers as to how to open a **single specific** `Drawable` from `MainActivity.java`, but not how to iterate over each `Drawable` from `res/drawables`. The `Drawable`s names do not follow any patterns (e.g. being numbered from 0 to 25), so the answer suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947392/iterate-through-certain-images-in-res-drawable-mdpi) sadly doesn't solve my problem. Does anyone know how to do the latter?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterate through certain images in res/drawable-mdpi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947392/iterate-through-certain-images-in-res-drawable-mdpi)

Comment: @FerasAlSous: Since the drawables of my interest are not ordered (like in the link you posted), the answer there sadly doesn't answer my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, put your drawables into an arrays

```
<array name="dashboard_item_menu_drawable">
    <item>@drawable/ic_file_green</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_email_green</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_linear_scale_green</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_undo_green</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_check_circle_green</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_archive_green</item>
</array>
```

Then, iterate your array drawables

```
val icons = ArrayList<Int>()
val arr = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.dashboard_item_menu_drawable)
(0 until arr.length()).forEach {
    // get resource id of each drawable
    val icon = arr.getResourceId(it, -1)
    icons.add(icon)
}
```

Next, recycles resource

```
arr.recycle()
```

Then you can use your drawable

```
iconView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, icons[index]))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate through drawables that have similar names like: image1, image2, ..., image10 you can do it like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier("image" + i, "drawable", getPackageName());
        Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, id);
        // your code here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is to put the names of your drawables in a String array:

```java
String[] symbols = {"first_img", "second_img", "third_img", "fourth_img"};
```

Then iterate over them like this (I put the images into a GridLayout):

```java
for(String symbol : symbols) {
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier(symbol, "drawable", getPackageName());

    ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams imgParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, 300);
    imgParams.setMargins(30, 30, 30, 30);
    img.setLayoutParams(imgParams);
    img.setBackgroundResource(id);
    symbolGrid.addView(img);
}
```